# Missing symbolic link in /usr/local/lib

Tags: c++, linux, linker, embedded-linux, bsp

For my embedded linux (TI AM335x) board, I have a SDK containing subfolders sysroot and filesystem. E.g. for libz:

sysroot/.../usr/lib contains:

```
libz.so         # symbolic link to libz.so.1.2.7
libz.so.1       # symbolic link to libz.so.1.2.7
libz.so.1.2.7
```

filesystem/usr/lib/ contains

```
libz.so.1       # symbolic link to libz.so.1.2.7
libz.so.1.2.7
```

The file system does not contain the symbolic link libz.so --> libz.so.1.2.7. But my linker want it. So I added it.
My questions: Is there any common reason not provide such symbolic links? Which goal is achieved by that?

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is so programs linking to the library can specify just a "soname", which is linked to the "real name" of the library.  If you decide to upgrade the library, the linker now links to the latest version instead of always having to change the linker configuration.  If you want more information about this, check [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html).

Comment: This is the reason to provide symbolic links to the newest version. But I asked for a reason why the system in use does not provide such a link.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Is there any common reason not provide such symbolic links? Which goal is achieved by that?
```

The only reason for concern is if there is a library API change between the symlink version of the library and the installed library. In that case, you will either get linker error if a needed function name isn't found, or you will get broken code if all names are the same, but operation of a given function has changed in between versions. When you manually create symlinks to shared libraries, **you** take on the responsibility to insure that the library calls you need are the same between the shared object library versions. Generally, when a library changes its `soname` (shared object name), it does so because there is some underlying change in the library that users of that library need to be aware of and confirm proper use. The fact that you need `libz.so` and your system has `libz.so.1` indicates such a change or **soname bump** occurred. You need to confirm that the features you need from `libz.so` are present and remain unchanged in `libz.so.1`. (most of the time libraries are backwards compatible, but at times they are not [e.g. libpng-1.2 and libpng-1.4])

That is the whole point with sonames. When you find yourself in the situation you are in either needing to create a symlink manually, or downgrade libz to get the needed `libz.so` -- the soname change tells you that **there have been library changes between libz.so and libz.so.1** so it is up to you to verify you can use `libz.so.1` symlinked to `libz.so` in the manner you are attempting to do.

Why should you even need the symlink? Why shouldn't your code be happy just using `libz.so.1` in place of `libz.so` without the symlink? The code you are compiling is looking for `libz.so`. As you have found, it is not present on your system. By providing the `libz.so -> libz.so.1` symlink you allow your code to find `libz.so.1` through the name `libz.so` without modifying your code. Creating the symlink is basically just a hack to work-around fixing your code to work with `libz.so.1`. Depending on your access to the code on either system, that may be necessary, but the proper way to handle this situation is to update both systems and the code to build with/use the current library `libz.so.1`

All that being said, if the changes to `libz.so.1` don't affect any part of `libz.so` you need to use, then the symlink works just fine.